# Macro for doing a switch on strings

Tags: c

Outside of using a hash function, I'd like to write a basic mapping of a key/value lookup of a few movie-credits related items. Does the following macro seem like an acceptable way to do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TOMAP(input_str, output_buf, from, to)  \
    if (strcmp(input_str, from) == 0) \
        strcpy(output_buf, to)

void map_imdb_position(const char* pos, char output[])
{
    TOMAP(pos, output, "Director", "director");
    TOMAP(pos, output, "Writer", "scribe");
}

int main(void) {
    char position[20];
    map_imdb_position("Director", position);
    printf("Director->%s\n", position);
}
```

If not, what might be a better approach to doing a sort of `switch` statement on a string comparison?

Comment: Why not just write a regular function and let your compiler optimize it if necessary? This macro could go wrong in a number of ways.

Comment: Why are you using both `char*` and `char[]` interchangeably here? It's worth picking one style and sticking to it, they both mean effectively the same thing as function arguments.

Comment: I'd put all your `from` and `to` strings in an array and iterate over it.  Just as (in)efficient and much simpler syntax.

Comment: @tadman I think I had `char*` and was returning that at first and then I decided to write it to the user-supplied buffer.

Comment: @NateEldredge you mean two separate arrays with the same length and use the index to match them with a `for` loop?

Comment: Is the purpose of this code to normalize certain labels into a particular form, like `"Director"` becomes `"director"`? I like Nate's idea of having a simple translation table you can spin through and use to convert. Quick and easy so long as you don't have thousands of these. Also an option: Regular expressions?

Comment: If you like, but an array of `struct`s would be cleaner.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, thanks for the suggestion. How does the approach below in the answer look?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments a cleaner way to do this would be with a map of credits in a function, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct map {
    char from[20];
    char to[20];
} Map;

void map_imdb_position(const char* credit, char output[])
{
    static Map credits[] = {
        {"Director", "director"}, 
        {"Writer", "scribe"}
    };
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(credits)/sizeof(*credits); i++) {
        if (strcmp(credit,credits[i].from) == 0) {
            strcpy(output, credits[i].to);
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%s --> %s\n", credit, output);
}

int main(void) {
    char position[20];
    map_imdb_position("Director", position);
    map_imdb_position("Writer", position);
}
```

Working example: https://onlinegdb.com/Sk_t76aQ_

Comment: Looks pretty good to me.  I'd probably separate the tasks of finding the replacement and copying by just having `map_imdb_position` return a pointer to the `to` string that was found, or `NULL` if not found.  Then the caller can copy or do whatever else it wants with it.  You currently have the odd situation that if there's no match, the output string is left uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

*Side note:* I was working on this solution but Carl already came up with a similar one.

But, I prefer to use the `ptr->field` syntax and to have an end-of-table sentinel at the end (vs. the `sizeof` construct to get the count).

And, I think designated initializers when constructing the table make things more readable [especially if more fields need to be added to the `struct`].

So, here's my version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    const char *from;
    const char *to;
} mapimdb_t;

mapimdb_t mapimdb[] = {
    { .from = "Director", .to = "director" },
    { .from = "Writer", .to = "scribe" },
    // ...
    { .from = NULL }
};

void
map_imdb_position(const char *pos, char *output)
{

    for (const mapimdb_t *map = mapimdb;  map->from != NULL;  ++map) {
        if (strcmp(pos,map->from) == 0) {
            strcpy(output,map->to);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void
dotest(const char *from,char *out)
{

    map_imdb_position(from,out);
    printf("dotest: %s->%s\n",from,out);
}

int
main(void)
{
    char position[20];

    dotest("Director", position);
    dotest("Writer", position);
}
```

Comment: _Side note:_ I've done it before, so if you're really doing IMDB scraping, you're a man after my own heart :-)

Comment: ha, not in C though. You can try this which is pretty good if you're not looking for the nitty gritty: https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/

Answer (score 0):

[X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) can be used:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LIST \
     X("Director", "director") \
     X("Writer", "scribe")


void map_imdb_position(const char* pos, char output[])
{
#define X(from, to) \
    if (strcmp(pos, from) == 0) \
        { strcpy(output, to); return; }  // "return" was missing?
STR_LIST
#undef X
}

int main(void) {
    char position[20];
    map_imdb_position("Director", position);
    printf("Director->%s\n", position);
}
```